# IE browser doesn't close and file download popup needs focus

Tags: watir, autoit

I am trying to to click on a link after it is active which again
produces a popup ( file download) after clicking.
Here i have 2 problems

1) I start the code and leave it .what the code does is -after long
process -it waits for the link to be active .Once the link is active
it clicks on the link and a download popups opens (if everything goes
well) and then it hangs there ( showing yellow flashing in the task
bar which mean i have to click on the explorer for it to process
whatever is next  ).every time i have to click on the IE whenever the
download popup appears .Is there a way to handle this or am i doing
some wrong ?

2) The next problem is even if i click on the IE .the IE doesn't get
close even though i write ie.close .
my code is below :

```
                       ## if the link is active
                    ie.link(:text,a).click_no_wait
                     prompt_message = "Do you want to open or save this file?"
                     window_title = "File Download"
                     save_dialog =WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
                       save_dialog.WinGetText(window_title)

                       save_dialog_obtained =save_dialog.WinWaitActive(window_title)
                        save_dialog.WinKill(window_title)
                      # end
                      #'
                       #some more code -normal puts statements
                      #

                    ie.close
```

ie is hanging up for some strange reason ..?

Comment: I'd love to know what those tags mean :-)

Comment: AutoIt is a script language focusing on Windows UI manipulation. A great tool to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

For #2. You would want to 'attach' your code to the parent window and then try to close it. Looks like when the download dialog opens, the parent window is losing focus. You could try -

ie = Watir::IE.attach(:url, ) (OR)
ie = Watir::IE.attach(:title, )

and then try to close the browser.

Comment: attach is I believe being depricated btw.  Watir 3 uses the same window switching api that watir-webdriver users.  however I think the popup in this case is not a browser window, and has to be handled at the OS level using something like AutoIt or RAutomation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your popup issue, but I have code to deal with what I found to be a very frustrating popup problem of my own. So I include it for completeness. Here your ie browser object is equivalent to my @browser instance object

```
require 'watir\winClicker'
require 'watir\contrib\enabled_popup'

def popup_clicker(text)
    begin
      Timeout::timeout 2 , PopupTimeout do
        if @browser.enabled_popup
          hwnd = @browser.enabled_popup(5)
          w = WinClicker.new
          w.makeWindowActive(hwnd)
          w.clickWindowsButton_hwnd(hwnd,text)
        end
      end
    rescue PopupTimeout
        # Do this line if you can't find a popup
    end
    @browser.wait
  end
```

Then to click the OK button just run

```
popup_clicker('OK')
```

One thing you might notice is that you need to manually click the button that fires the popup with a hardware click. AutoIT might handle that, or I have a manual Watir element clicker if you want it. Try it without first. I also have code to check the popup contents if you want that (basically throw 'popup_text = w.getStaticText_hWnd(hwnd).to_s' into it).

As for 2) make sure the 'ie' object is still set to the browser. Try reattaching, as Namrantha noted. I've not known ie.close to fail. This should work, replacing @browser as you see fit, and XXX being the title of the window or a regex equivalent:

```
@browser = Watir::IE.attach(:title, XXXX)
@browser.close
```

Credit for the popup clicker original has to go to the furthest back in the chain I can find, a lovely user on the Watir-General google group called Wesley Chen:

http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/41c45aae9f87da9b